# Fullscreen video bg in div that behaves like the div is its alpha?

Tags: html, css, video

The effect I'm going for here is to have a main full-screen video as the background and on top of that I want to have a div that centered and have it look like the background video gets blurred by this div, and to do this I'm trying to use another version of the video that is pre-blurred and on-top of the bg video but I only want this video to be visible where the div is, and the div is moving dynamically independent of the background, so would be like the div were the alpha channel for the blurred video, hopes this makes sense.

Here an image of the look I'm trying for:
[image]

and here is as jsfiddle of what I have so far:
**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/04mx0guv/)**

***.::CODE::.***

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<video autoplay loop muted id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://www.patan77.com/screenshot/test_bg_vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop muted id="bgvid_blur">
    <source src="http://www.patan77.com/screenshot/test_bg_vid_blur.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#main{
  position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}

video#bgvid_blur { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -99;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Experimented with clip path a bit, and its closer to what I want (but still not really), but noticed another problem the videos (blur and the not blurred version) don't play in sync, and don't know how I would make sure they are always in sync, damn this turned out to be a bit harder then I initially thought it would be.

**[JSFIDDLE_v02](https://jsfiddle.net/04mx0guv/1/)**

Comment: Your best bet now is to rely on the experimental `backdrop-filter` property. Trying to size the blurred video dynamically while retaining its fixed positioning is going to be challenging, as you will probably have to rely on CSS masks (which is almost just as experimental).

Comment: If you don't mind doing a lot of JavaScript stuff, you fake it by sticking a canvas behind your div. The canvas would be displaying input from the video (I _think_ this is possible...), and of course would be cropped to only be behind your div. Then, use `filter: blur` on the canvas. Of course, `filter` isn't supported in IE...

Comment: backdrop-filter the support almost non existing so wont be able to use that, also I would think blurring a video in real-time with that would be to compute intensive, also I would prefer to pre-blur myself because then I can use more advanced DOF blurs etc, I experimented a bit with the clipping path, and it kind of works a bit but don't know how to use the div as the path also noticed that the videos don't play in sync .